# file_get_contents и субдомены

Tags: php, file-get-contents

```
try {.
  $content = file_get_contents('https://meridian.sparkes.zone/');


} catch (Exception $e) {
    // Handle exception
}
echo $content;
```

С ссылками типа http и https всё работает, но при вбиве субдомена всё ломается.

Ловлю:

```
file_get_contents(): SSL operation failed with code 1. OpenSSL Error messages:
error:14077410:SSL routines:SSL23_GET_SERVER_HELLO:sslv3 alert handshake failure
```

Памагити!1

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`try-catch`, не поймает исключение `file_get_contents`, так-как, работает только с классами или с методами / функциями, которые определяют `throw new Класс`.
 По этому в вашем случае - это избыточный код.
Для того, чтобы `try-catch` - все-же, начал перехватывать ошибки  `file_get_contents`, нужно воспользоваться `set_error_handler` или оператор подавления ошибок `@` (не рекомендую использовать данный оператор) и далее сравнивать пусто или нет и если да, вернуть `throw new Класс`.

```
set_error_handler(function($severity, $message, $file, $line) {
    throw new ErrorException($message, $severity, $severity, $file, $line);
});
try {
    $content = file_get_contents('https://meridian.sparkes.zone');
} catch (Exception $e) {
    echo $e->getMessage();
}
restore_error_handler();
```

> file_get_contents(): SSL operation failed with code 1. OpenSSL Error
>   messages: error:14077410:SSL routines:SSL23_GET_SERVER_HELLO:sslv3
>   alert handshake failure

Исправляется так:

```
$content = file_get_contents("https://meridian.sparkes.zone", false, stream_context_create([
    "ssl" => [
        "verify_peer" => false,
        "verify_peer_name" => false
    ]
]));
echo $content;
```

Comment: Теперь другая беда. Не пускает CloudFlare, можете помочь?)

Comment: @icYFTL, оформите развернуто с кодом и описанием, что делаете в новый вопрос.